# FindAll() not working in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

My model name is Sales.

```
$allSales = Sales::model()->findAll();
```

$allSales return nothing (Blank). But its working my local computer(Ubuntu) and **Not working on live server (Mac)**.

```
$allSales2 = Sales::model()->findAll("id < 2000");
```

$allSales2 is working on both server

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's odd. Do you have some default scope defined in the model? Are you using the correct database and are there records in the sales table? Asking just in case, I never had problems with findAll().

Answer (score 1):

(Blank) is vague, but if the page itself is blank when it loads you are likely seeing an out of memory error. This is common with a large number of active records being queried at once. Check the php_error.log file and the respective memory limits in php.ini on each server.

You can also try to use [CDataProviderIterator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProviderIterator) to fetch all the models, instead of `findAll()`.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Sales');
$allSales = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider);

foreach ($allSales as $model) {
    //do whatever
}
```

If your issue IS a memory problem, this should get around it.

If not, add `var_dump($allSales);` to your original code, and report the results from the live server.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the conditions as array. Try like this

```
$allSales2 = Sales::model()->findAll(
    array(
         "condition" => "id <  2000"
    )
);
```

If you do not like to use array in findAll then can use CDbCriteria like below

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = '*';
$criteria->condition = 'id < 2000';
$allSales2 = Sales::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want use findAll() without any condition.

Comment: @RajibRakshit, using findAll("somevalue") IS using a condition.